# When do you use threading in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was told that using threading in Python is not a good practice because of the GIL. I think the overhead of creating threads will just slow things down and eventually make it slower than a single threaded application.
Then, why would Python have the threading library in the first place? When should you use threading?

(I am assuming Python3)

Comment: Threading doesn't help for compute-bound processes. Fortunately, it can help a lot with I/O-bound processes, such as Web applications.

Answer (score 1):

@kindall has given the answer in his comment.

Multi-threading is not a magic tool that speeds up any processing. It is a way to have multiple threads present in system at the same time. It *can* be used to split processing on multiple cores  for compute-bound processing (this one not in CPython because of the Global Interpreter Lock). But it can also be used for io-bound processing: one thread runs while the others wait for io completion. A nice example of that is a multithreaded TCP server where each thread can serve a different client connection. CPython implemention is good here because the GIL has no reason to block a thread that is already blocked at io level.

And just to end on general multi-threading: it should **never** be used for memory bound processing...

Answer (score 0):

`GIL` is not a problem of python itself, it is a problem of its `cpython` implementation, as the memory management in cpython implementation is not threadsafe.

`Cpython` is implemented with a global lock on the python interpreter. So, one particular python CPU bound operation can be run on a particular interpreter at a particular time. So, no matter you are running single/multiple thread, it's all the same.

But, imagine, if there is some I/O bound task, like database queries, or file operations, where python code isn't actually get executed, you can be benefited greatly with `multithreading`.

Comment: Adding on to this, I recently used Python threading to run a stepper motor. Because I don't want the function to block while it runs the motor one-step over and over, I used another thread to run the motor continuously.